# If I redirect all users (Except me) from within .htaccess, do I need a robots.txt file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect, robots.txt

So.. I have my live version of my site e.g v1.0 at domain.com

I then have my development testing version at testing.domain.com

I want testing.domain.com to only be accessible to me for testing, and as such I redirect all other IPs in my .htaccess file to the current live version at domain.com

Given this, do I need to have a robots.txt file on testing.domain.com to block search robots, or will the .htaccess redirect suffice?

Tiny extra little question.. should such a redirect be a 301 permanent redirect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is sufficient. Yes, best practice for this kind of redirect use case is a 301.